# How to wake up the Client Thread in Below Situation?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking

```
class Server
{
   while(true)
   new ClientThread(Socket.accept()).start();
}
class ClientThread extends Thread
{
   public void run()
    {
       ppl.chat(Socket s);//a defined protocol object in my program
     }
}
class Protocol
{
   public Protocol(Socket s)
    {
           socket=s;
     }
    public synchronized void chat()
    {
       //here i defined socket input output streams and serverinput is a string given     by server
       if(ServerInput=="wait")
        wait();
       if(ServerInput=="cont")
        notify()
        .....................sending infomation-------
      }
}
```

Here I am able to go away from the `wait()` block after that i can't able to send the information via this socket. I tested it is successfully coming out of the wait block. When it is notified by giving "cont" from other Client Thread.
anyone solve my problem? Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudo-code is a very confusing IMHO but what I would do is.

Only use the client thread for reading, not writing.

When you want to write, obtain a write lock (don't lock the entire object) or send the message in a single write (which does much the same thing)

This way the reading thread only needs to wake when there is something to read.

This means you don't need wait or notify which I would suggest you use in any case.  If you needed them, you should use the High Level concurrency libraries added in Java 5.0 (but not in this case)